# Which is safer for Algorithm implementation?

Tags: android

I've a data processing algorithm which I will apply for one of my Android Application. The Algorithm can be implemented via Java or Native Code C. But which is safer for algorithm implementation Java or C as so far I know Android Dex file can be reversed engineered. Is it also applicable for C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code safety is maximum when you do it in C(native) than java.

> "so far I know Android Dex file can be reversed engineered. Is it also
>   applicable for C?"

**Doing it in JAVA**

By making your code-pakages to library you can make your java codes safe. Even if its reverse engineerd or your apk is breaked your code will not be visible, It will be like encrypted format. Change you algorithm package to library and add to the project assets folder and buildpath.

**Doing it in C**

And if you are doing it in C its sure that one who breaks your apk cant see your C code. Sometime it will be visible but it will not be in readble format. If you are implementing it via C, it will make the process more faster than in java and also you will be allocated more memory to do the process. Heap memory will not be a limitation for you code. The only thing is, Because of using JNI chances of getting errors are more and it will be difficult to trackdown the errors in runtime.

*NOTE* :Since hacking can be done in many ways.. I cant give any compleate assurance..But in most of the ways this is the thing ..Making your algorithm packages to library and adding it to project with buildpath **or** doing it in native, you can make your code safe to maximum extend..

Answer (score 4):

If you want your algorithm to be perfectly safe, keep it in your head.

If you want your algorithm to be relatively safe, keep it on your server.

Any code can be reverse-engineered. People have been reverse-engineering compiled C code for decades. Bytecodes for interpreters, like Java and Dalvik, tend to be easier to reverse-engineer, bringing it within the skill set of more people. However, that tends to be of greater concern where what's being protected is software licensing. If you are worried about "a data processing algorithm" outside of licensing, your average script kiddie isn't going to care about it, and a competitor who really wants to know what that algorithm is can figure it out if they have access to the code, whether you wrote it in Java, C, or hand-coded assembler.

Hence, if you do not want people to reverse-engineer your code, do not let them have the code. Keep the algorithm on your server.

If your response to that is "I do not want my app to have a dependency on a server", you are explicitly stating that your "data processing algorithm" is not important, at least compared to having that dependency. And at that point, you really have to start asking the question of how important the "data processing algorithm" is altogether.